# How to store an array of strings from a file input into a struct element in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, file-io

So I have this text file (cartCoords.txt):

```
a = 2b, 1d; milk cheese eggs
b = 2a, 1e, 2c;
c = 2b, 1f;
d = 1a, 1g;
e = 1h, 1b;
f = 1i, 1c;
g = 1j, 1d;
h = 1k, 1e;
i = 1l, 1f;
j = 1m, 1g;
k = 1n, 1h;
l = 1o, 1i;
m = 2n, 1j;
n = 2m, 1k, 2o;
o = S, 2n, 1l;
```

These represent my version of a map layout. Point "a" is 2 units away from "b" and 1 unit away from "d" and at point a, we have the items "milk", "cheese", and "eggs".

I've constructed a struct:

```
struct stopPoints {
   char **items;
   char connectingPoints[10];
   int  weights[10];
   int startBool;
};
```

So each "stop point" (a,b,c...etc) contains a list of items (milk, cheese, etc), a list of connected points (the b and d in 2b and 1d), the "weight" of each corresponding connecting point (the 2 and 1 in 2b and 1d), and a boolean value representing if it's a start point or not (indicated by an "S).

I've been able to store each connecting point and it's weight into each point's struct, but I'm having trouble storing each individual string of items into an array. What I want to do is for each struct to have an array that stores each item in each index, like this:

```
["milk", "cheese", "eggs"]
```

How would I go about doing this?

```
Below is my code:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 10

struct stopPoints {
   char **theItem;
   char connectingPoints[10];
   int  weights[10];
   int startBool;
};


struct stopPoints makeStruct(char* str)
{
    char items[10];
    int i,j=0,k=0, l=0, semiCheck =0, a;
    struct stopPoints point;

    for(i=4; i<strlen(str); i++)
    {
        //check if its a starting point
        if(i==4 && str[i] == 'S')
        {
            point.startBool = 1;
            i+=3;
        }
        else if(i==4)
        {
            point.startBool = 0;
        }

        //if there's no semicolon present, proceed with the code
       if (semiCheck == 0) {
            //checks if its a number
            if(str[i] < 58 && str[i] > 47){
                point.weights[j] = str[i];
                j++;
            }
            //checks if its a letter
            else if(str[i] < 122 && str[i] > 96){
                point.connectingPoints[k] = str[i];
                k++;
            }

            else if (str[i] == 59){
                semiCheck = 1;
                i++;
                }
            }
        else if(semiCheck==1){
             for (a=1; a<(strlen(str)-i); a++){
                if (str[i+a] != 32){
                    items[a-1] = str[i+a];
                }
        }

       }

    }
    return point;
}

int main(){
    int selections[100];
    int numOfItems,x,y,j,z,temp;
    int i = 0;
    struct stopPoints store[26];

    FILE *fp;
    char str[60];

    /* opening file for reading */
    fp = fopen("cartCoords.txt" , "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
      perror("Error opening file");
      return(-1);
    }

    while( fgets (str, 600, fp)!= NULL ) {
      /* writing content to stdout */
      //printf("test1");
      store[i] = makeStruct(str);
      i++;
      printf("store[%d] connecting points = %c and %c and %c\n", i-1, store[i-1].connectingPoints[0], store[i-1].connectingPoints[1], store[i-1].connectingPoints[2]);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
store[0] connecting points = b and d and
store[1] connecting points = a and e and c
store[2] connecting points = b and f and
store[3] connecting points = a and g and
store[4] connecting points = h and b and
store[5] connecting points = i and c and
store[6] connecting points = j and d and
store[7] connecting points = k and e and
store[8] connecting points = l and f and
store[9] connecting points = m and g and
store[10] connecting points = n and h and
store[11] connecting points = o and i and
store[12] connecting points = n and j and
store[13] connecting points = m and k and o
store[14] connecting points = n and l and
```

So I've been able to properly store the letters and numbers. I just don't know how to take a complete string and store it into an array. My approach was to have my loop check for a semicolon (using its ascii value) and once a semicolon is detected, it would start gathering each separate string. The only problem is is that I have no idea how to implement that.

Comment: Once you have a pointer to the character after the semicolon, you can use `strtok` to break the line into individual tokens. You need to count the tokens, then `malloc` memory for pointers, then `malloc` memory for each string, then use `strcpy` to copy the strings. When allocating memory for a string, remember to allocate one extra byte to hold the NUL terminator.

Comment: Move `i++` after the `printf()` so you don't have to use `i-1` in all the array references.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers like `str[i] < 58 && str[i] > 47`. C has built-in functions like `isdigit()` and `islower()`.

Comment: Or `str[i] <= '9' && str[i] >= '0'`

Comment: @Barmar agreed, and (to OP) one thing worse than hard coding a value is to also hard code adjacent values. When the sun rises and you realise they should refer to a common definition, that makes the job even harder. Moroever when you do that edit and you have hard coded say `< 8` and `<= 7` it is a dangerous job to distinguish them from every other `8` and `7` that you have hard coded in another context.

Comment: Also, just a curiosity, why use a *relative* instead *absolute* coordinate system?

Comment: @user3386109 thanks for your input! I was able to figure out how to split each different word in the string.Now i just have to figure out how to store each of them in the struct....